# sequelize Bulkcreate: Ignore if single row fails

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js, koa2

I have to import rows from a `.csv`, and put them in my database (chunks of 500). To do this i'm using the sequelize `bulkCreate` functionality.

I have a field called `address` which is required (not nullable). If one of the rows fails to insert (because the row in my csv doesn't have an address) the entire batch fails. what I want to achieve is that `bulkCreate` attempts to insert the lines, and ignores the ones which fail.

Anyway to achieve this? Here's my current code if it helps

```
export const createEnterprise = async (rows: any[]) => {
  try {
    // Create enterprise record
    await models.enterprise.bulkCreate(rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err
  }
};
```

Comment: There is a non-null constraint on the `address` column of the `Enterprise` table. Maybe you can filter the rows use the application code firstly. Then, you can insert the cleaned and satisfied the non-null constraint data.